Recoil Provider not working in Nextjs, not working even after wrapping body in layout.tsx
layout.tsx
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ClientRecoilProvider } from "../providers/recoil-provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Turborepo",
  description: "Generated by create turbo",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
      
    <html lang="en">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <ClientRecoilProvider>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          
        {children}
        </body>
      </ClientRecoilProvider>
    </html>
  );
}

recoil-provider.tsx
"use client"; // This makes it a client component
import { RecoilRoot } from "recoil";

export const ClientRecoilProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <RecoilRoot>{children}</RecoilRoot>;
};

I get the error that
 Error: This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component.
    at useBalance (../../packages/store/src/hooks/useBalance.ts:10:73)
    at Page (./app/page.tsx:11:84)
digest: "4224829649"




'use client'
import { useBalance } from "@repo/store/balance";

const Page = () => {
  const balance = useBalance();
  return ( 
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-2xl">Welcome to User App {balance}</h1>
    </div>
   );
}
 
export default Page;

above is where i call the hook
I try to implement a simple hook in recoil and I know that in order to use that hook, that hook must be called inside a  wrapped component. So I wrapped my html body in layout.tsx but I get the error that  Error: This component must be used inside a  component.
at useBalance (../../packages/store/src/hooks/useBalance.ts:10:73)
at Page (./app/page.tsx:11:84)
digest: "4224829649"
